# Highlighting a property in combobox

Tags: windows-os, combobox, highlight

I am currently doing an application with a combobox, like this:

[image: example of a combobox]

Obviously the visuals can be better, but leaving that aside: How can I highlight a boolean property of a particular element? A bullet? Text color? In particular, the property indicates whether the entry has related images or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using (what looks to me) a standard component I assume that customization is limited. Therefore I would suggest that you use something that is easily accomplished, noticeable and recognizable.

[The Unicode for the paperclip would probably work great](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4ce/index.htm).

[image]

That cues that there's something attached to the item (an image), it's clearly visible (especially in a list where all items has the same length, which it looks like all do in your example) and conveniently it's a Unicode asset and should be easy to integrate in the Windows standard component.

Comment: Thank you, I really liked the paperclip suggestion. It wasn't easy, though, the compiler didn't accept it as a unicode char and when forced to, fonts united against me. Luckily windows allows you to draw your controls yourself(voluntarily) so I ended up doing so and loading and painting a bmp icon. Looks nicer now :)

Comment: @chubakueno I'm glad to hear it finally turned out well! I guess I shouldn't really bother with estimating implementation complexity, since I'm a bit too unfamiliar with that trait. Good thing you managed to turn it around though!

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination of the two would work.  We do this a lot inhouse where we have to highlight a selection for the user so that when they are scanning the dropdown, they can easily see their current selection.  BUT, because you are also indicating an image is attached, I do like the suggestion of adding some visual treatment near the control showing that something is indeed "attached."  You also see that "attached" visual treatment in many things like email, etc., so it should easily be recognizable as something is attached to this control/selection.